# Flutter Blue Read characteristic is returning error

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

I want simply to read the values of the characteristics of my services. But I'm getting this error:
[[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(read_characteristic_error, unknown reason, may occur if readCharacteristic was called before last read finished., null)]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP9lZ.png)

My Code:

```java
 discoverServices() async {
     List<BluetoothService services = await device.discoverServices();
     services.forEach((service) async {
       // do something with service
       if (service.uuid.toString() == SERVICE_UUID) {
         var characteristics = await service.characteristics;
         for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
           //if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
             targetCharacteristic = c;
             List<int value = await c.read();
             print(value);
           //}
         };
       }
     });   }
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn0NR.png)

Any idea of what's happening here?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. I would make sure your GATT Service that is being passed your services has all unique UUIDS.
2. I would give the code below a shot. I've done a dozen apps with Flutter Blue at this point and the only issues I have seen are to do with reads and responses.

   ```
   discoverServices() async {
     List<BluetoothService> services;
     BluetoothService myImportantService;
     List<BluetoothCharacteristic> characteristics;
     BluetoothCharacteristic myImportantCharacteristic;

     //Get your services from your device.
     services = await device.discoverServices();

     //Find the service we are looking for.
     for(BluetoothService s in services) {
       //Would recommend to convert all to lowercase if comparing.
       if(s.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == SERVICE_UUID)
         myImportantService = s;
     }

     //Get this services characteristics.
     characteristics = myImportantService.characteristics;

     //Find the characteristic we are looking for.
     for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
       //Would recommend to convert all to lowercase if comparing.
       if(c.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
         myImportantCharacteristic = c;
     }

     List<int> data = await myImportantCharacteristic.read();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code is very clear however I get the same error:  `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(read_characteristic_error, unknown reason, may occur if readCharacteristic was called before last read finished., null)'. Any suggestion?`

Comment: What code is wrapping these function? Are you "polling" this function or any other reads? What hardware/software are you using for GATTServer?